# How to read data from xml in postgresql function?

Tags: xml, postgresql, stored-procedures

how to read the xml data in postgresql stored procedure.and how to send data through xml and call stored procedure in java.

i can read the xml data through ***sqlserver*** but same thing i use in postgres stored procedure like

```
insert into temp_StudentDetails (studentId, studentFirstName, studentMiddleName, studentLastName, dateOfBirth, emailId, mobileNumber, landlineNumber, courseId, yearId, cityIdPass, stateIdPass, addressId)
    SELECT 
        Tab.Col.value('(studentId)[1]', 'bigint' ),
        Tab.Col.value('(studentFirstName)[1]', 'character varying(50)'),
        Tab.Col.value('(studentMiddleName)[1]', 'character varying(50)'),
        Tab.Col.value('(studentLastName)[1]', 'character varying(50)'),
        Tab.Col.value('(dateOfBirth)[1]', 'date'),
        Tab.Col.value('(emailId)[1]', 'character varying(50)'),
        Tab.Col.value('(mobileNumber)[1]', 'character varying(50)'),
        Tab.Col.value('(landlineNumber)[1]', 'character varying(50)'),
        Tab.Col.value('(courseId)[1]', 'BIGINT'),
        Tab.Col.value('(yearId)[1]', 'BIGINT'),
        Tab.Col.value('(cityIdPass)[1]', 'BIGINT'),
        Tab.Col.value('(stateIdPass)[1]', 'BIGINT'),
        Tab.Col.value('(addressId)[1]', 'BIGINT')

        from p_studentDetailsXML.nodes('/Root/StudentDetails') Tab(Col);
```

and How to make it  work in **postgresql** function?

Any help?

Comment: What's this `Tab.Col.Value()` function doing? But you probably want the [xpath()](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-xml.html#FUNCTIONS-XML-PROCESSING) and [xpath_table()](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/xml2.html#AEN162085) functions

Comment: it's the syntax used in SQL Server to read the xml string pass to stored procedure from java and now i had to change database to postgres. So how can i read xml string in postgres function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Postgres offers a good support for writing and reading xml data. See documentation for more info:
[www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-xml.html](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-xml.html)

The extension xml2 provide extra xml functionality:
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/xml2.html.
Create the extension with

```
CREATE EXTENSION xml2;
```

As a_horse_with_no_name said, you need probably the fuction xpath or xpath_table. Here a simple stored procedure example based on your data using the xpath function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insert_student(input_xml xml) RETURNS VOID AS
  $$
  DECLARE root_xpath TEXT = '/Root/StudentDetails/';
  BEGIN
    INSERT INTO temp_StudentDetails (studentId, studentFirstName)
    SELECT ((xpath(root_xpath|| 'StudentId/text()', input_xml))[1])::text::int,
          (xpath(root_xpath|| 'studentFirstName/text()', input_xml))[1];                
    RETURN;
  END;
  $$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

So you can call the function:

```
SELECT insert_student('
<Root><StudentDetails>
  <StudentId>10</StudentId>
  <studentFirstName>John</studentFirstName>
</StudentDetails></Root>');
```